# Pine stock scanner

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to build a stock scanner in Pine script (Tradingview)?
What I mean is a (for?) loop that scans each stock in one market and looks if the condition i.e. for oversold stocks (RSI<30) is fulfilled and prints it on the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `security` function, its would not be efficient but you could use

```
length = input(14)
f(sym)=>
    s = security(sym,timeframe.period,close)
    r = rsi(s,length) < 30 ? 1 : 0
//----
aapl = f("AAPL")
amd = f("AMD")
intel = f("INTC")
plot(aapl + amd + intel)
```

The script returns the number of the stocks in the scripts where `rsi < 30 = true`, you can also plot everything separately if you want, while using `label.new` can allow you to have more descriptive results.